# Cleaning sliding window gap

Tags: cleaning, metals

How to properly clean sliding window cavity?

Things I tried:

1. Using tooth brush - can't get 2 mm diameter particles out.
2. Using vacuum cleaner - though this was quite effective I was not able to get clean surface. Because we all know how persistent dust particles are on old surface!!

[image]

Comment: Which part are you trying to clean? Are you cleaning for reasons of appearance or for some functional reason like the window gets jammed at a certain point?

Comment: I am cleaning for appearance.

Comment: I think I'd be looking at using a pan scourer, wire wool or some similar lightly abrasive thing

Comment: a steam cleaner would blast that gunk away in seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try the following:

1) Scour the trough with steel wool, to loosen all particles.

2) Brush the loosened particles to one end of the trough.

3) Use a vacuum (especially with a narrow attachment!) to get out as many particles as you can. You can also sweep / brush the particles to the end *again*, and vacuum them out *again*.

4) To remove the final particles, use an air blower such as a can of compressed air or the output stream from a vacuum. You should probably be running the vacuum on the same area, so the particles get sucked up instead of flying all over the place.

Comment: Consider also using an exacto/craft/Stanley knife (whatever they’re called in your region of the world) to get into small gaps and remove or crush trapped particles so they can be more easily cleaned out. Consider using stainless wool, so that fragments of it don’t linger, rust and worsen appearance